# How can I change the scale of an axis to be in radians?

Tags: plotting, rescale

I want to plot the function $\sin(x)$ versus $x$. The problem is that I want to scale $x$ based on radian angles (like $\pi/6, \pi/3, \ldots$).

But as we see in the image below, it's not based on pi-type angles. How can I do that?

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Table[z, {z, 0, 2 \[Pi], Pi/6}], 
    None}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Or replace `Table[z, {z, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}]` with `Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6]`